# What is the probability that all books of the same language land next to each other in a random arrangement?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

4 different Mathematics books, 3 different German books, and 3 different Spanish books are arranged randomly on a shelf. What is the probability that all books of the same language will land next to each other?

I assumed that we would have $$\frac{4!\cdot3!\cdot3!\cdot(3!)}{10!}=\frac{1}{700}$$
where the $3!$ in brackets would be for the 3 groups being arranged in different ways... but this is wrong according to the book's solutions' manual. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is mathematics considered a language? If not you might do MGGGMSSSMM, for example.

Comment: @barakmanos do you recall the solution ? ....

Comment: @symplectomorphic I don't think that math would be considered as a language

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1501484/131263), which is almost the same, except for the fact that it asks about the number of arrangements instead of probability. But as @symplectomorphic mentioned, Mathematics is probably not considered a language (otherwise your solution would be correct).

Comment: @Dan: well your solution only works if math is considered a language.

Comment: So in order to fix your solution, it seems like you should only replace the $(3!)$ with $(2!)$.

Comment: @barakmanos: no. there are $6!\cdot3!\cdot3!$ ways to arrange the books so German and Spanish are grouped together -- 6 because we glue German and Spanish into 2 units, and then have the 4 math. then we permute German and Spanish within each unit.

Answer (score 3):

Treat all german and spanish books as one, and find the number of arrangements. For each arrangemment you have 3!3! allocations of language books. Now divide through 10!